# Sphinx Search is not working

Tags: php, sphinx

I updated the sphinx to 64bit which was 32 bit earlier. I am getting proper result in command prompt, but while testing in php site it is giving me garbage value although i have updated sphinxapi.php to 64 bit version. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its not the still the 32 bit searchd still running?

Try issusing "searchd --stop" and check ps/top to make sure it dead/gone. If not then use "killall -9 searchd" to be sure.

Then try starting the daemon normally.

... other you should be clearer on what 'garbage' means.